# Kendo: Direction property for context main menu

Tags: javascript, html, css, kendo-ui

I would like to use **direction** option for **kendo context main menu** items. I have searched in the Kendo documentation and found that direction option available for Kendo context sub-menu items and Kendo Menu items.

Kendo Doc Ref: https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/contextmenu

But in my case, I need to use kendo context menu in the rightmost corner of DIV, So that opening the context menu should fall inside the div not exceeding it.

```
My code: https://codepen.io/JGSpark/pen/XYQjmR
```

The context menu option should fall within DIV, a meaning menu should open towards left.

Any suggestion would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Since my other answer was deleted for no reason at all, here you can see the things i referenced with my old answer (why would someone delete an answer to such a small audience!?!):

Maybe this helps: KendoUi: [Right-to-left support](https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/menu/right-to-left-support)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/kendo.common.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/kendo.default.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/kendo.rtl.min.css" />   <!-- Add this to your hmtl -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/kendo.default.mobile.min.css" />
    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="example">
        <div class="demo-section k-content k-rtl"> <!-- The k-rtl property makes the context menu go to the left -->
            <ul id="menu">              <!-- Here is your context menu -->
                <li>...</li>
                <li>...</li>
                <li>...</li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $("#menu").kendoMenu();
            });
        </script>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```